# How to import external dependencies in gradle?

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

New to java development here. I'm using gradle in eclipse.

I want to import the JSONParser. In my code I  have:

```
    import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
```

and in build.gradle I have:

```
repositories {

    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {

    compile 'com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1.1'


}
```

However, when I try to build I get:

```
int/MainApp.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
import org.json.simple.parser;
                      ^
  symbol:   class parser
  location: package org.json.simple
1 error
```

What's going on here? I think I don't understand exactly how gradle works.

Comment: can you change it `compile group: 'com.googlecode.json-simple', name: 'json-simple', version: '1.1.1'
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the jar files in a folder, for example in the lib folder in root directory, add the following to your gradle build

```
dependencies 
{
compile files('libs/something_local.jar')
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you added dependency later:

Right click on project -> gradle -> refresh

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try it, it may helpful for you:

```
 buildscript {
   ext {
     springBootVersion = '2.1.0.RELEASE'
   }
   repositories {
     mavenCentral()
   }
   dependencies {
     classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle- 
     plugin:${springBootVersion}")
  }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

 group = 'com.xyz'
 version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
 sourceCompatibility = 1.8

 repositories {
  mavenCentral()
 }

 dependencies {
   compile 'com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1.1'
 }
```

Comment: I'm not sure how gradle works. Do i need to download the jar?

Comment: what do u mean by that?

Comment: means got to ' Window->Preferences->General->Keys ' and do Build and Clean, it will clear and import all dependencies.